Acess Sitecore content editor ribbon item via sitecore powershell extension
How do I access Sitecore content editor's ribbon button using Sitecore PowerShell extension?
I need to use this validation button for all the items created and have a look at the errors (if any). Is there any way to run this using PowerShell? I can then update my PowerShell script to run via all the items.

any suggestion?
Thanks

Try this Powershell Script to execute showvalidationresult command.

Get-Item master:/content/home | Invoke-ShellCommand "contenteditor:showvalidationresult"

Read more details : Invoke-ShellCommand
Hope it helps!

Hi Sumit,
Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately, this did not work out. Can you please guide me how to find the parameter
-Name 
Name of the Sitecore command e.g. "item:publishingviewer"
specific to this validation button
PS master:\> Get-Item master:/content/home | Invoke-ShellCommand "<Name of the sitecore command for this validation button>"

contenteditor:showvalidationresult is a name of Sitecore command action that triggers when you click on the Validation button on the content editor ribbon. You can find it in Core database.

You can use the Invoke-ShellCommand to achieve this. Here are the examples of the code.
PS master:\> Get-Item master:/content/home | Invoke-ShellCommand "item:duplicate"

PS master:\> Get-Item master:\content\home\ | Invoke-ShellCommand "item:publishingviewer"

PS master:\> Get-Item master:/content/home | Invoke-ShellCommand "contenteditor:properties"

If you want to get the command for the button you are looking for, search for the file Sitecore.SecureCommands.config in your sitecore instance. The path will be /your-sitecore-instance/App_Config/Sitecore/CMS.Core/Sitecore.SecureCommands.config. You will get name of the commands.
Hope this helps.
